# loading jquery mobile 1.3.2 in requirejs error, nth-child not recognised

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, requirejs

I tried to load jQueryMobile 1.3.2. I also tried 1.3.1 with RequireJS, which returns an error : `error in requirejs Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child`.

Here is the code

```js
requirejs.config(
    {
        paths: {
            jquery: 'library/JQuery/jquery-1.8.3',
            jquerymobile: 'library/JQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2'
        },

        shim: {
            'jquery' : {
                exports: '$'
            },

            'jquerymobile' : {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'jm'
            }
        }
    }
);

//Check device ready, call app
requirejs(['jquery', 'jquerymobile'],
    function($, jm) {
        alert('clean');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems an empty u,l tag in html caused this error, weird, it stopped everything from loading